# RuntimeError: Ninja is required to load C++ extensions even after pip install ninja

Tags: python, c++, ninja

I am trying to run my DL model using torch. While running, I am facing this error:

```
UserWarning: Just-in-time loading and compiling the CUDA kernels of SRU was unsuccessful. Got the following error:
Ninja is required to load C++ extensions
  warnings.warn("Just-in-time loading and compiling the CUDA kernels of SRU was unsuccessful. "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sru/cuda_functional.py", line 15, in <module>
    load(
  File ""/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1080, in load
    return _jit_compile(
  File ""/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1293, in _jit_compile
    _write_ninja_file_and_build_library(
  File ""/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1374, in _write_ninja_file_and_build_library
    verify_ninja_availability()
  File ""/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1430, in verify_ninja_availability
    raise RuntimeError("Ninja is required to load C++ extensions")
RuntimeError: Ninja is required to load C++ extensions

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Now, the obvious solution was
`pip install ninja`
However, it shows that ninja is already installed/

Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe it's not on your PATH. If you run `which ninja` does it report it as found?

Comment: No it is not showing anything. Moreover, I found that the error is related to sru, when I am trying to do from sru import SRU... I already did pip install sru

Comment: Sorry, but your question should be "How to install ninja?" then. If you can't run it, it isn't installed properly. For such a question, the output of `pip` on installation might be important.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I mentioned pip install is already tried and it isn't working it seems, as pip install ninja shows module already exists

Comment: I understand that and that's exactly what prompted me to my comment. The problem you describe is secondary, but the primary problem isn't really approached, there's almost zero info on that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`conda install ninja` works for me.
As pip installing the ninja version 1.10, the conda installing ninja version is 1.7. I guess it's the problem about path